# how to create a responsive CSS positioned image in CSS3

Tags: css, image, position, responsive

I want to add responsive image to my header. It's looks perfect on my screen but when i change the screen size it's out of position.

HTML:

```
<section id="cover">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row text-center">
             <div class="col-sm-12 character">
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
    #cover {
    background: url('../img/coverBg.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 400px 100px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 400px 100px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

.character {
  background: url("../img/character.png") no-repeat center center;
  width: 170px;
  height: 245px;
  top: 67px;
}
```

[how should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv1QA.png)

[but how look on other screen sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1f3L.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a fixed width AND height. Set height: auto; and then you should see the correct ratio. Also, your CSS for .character has the width (170) narrower than the height (245) which would be a portrait view, but your example shows a landscape view.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.img-responsive{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
   margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.character{
  background:#ccc;
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<!-- Example 1 --->

<section id="cover">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row text-center">
             <div class="col-sm-12 character">
         
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv1QA.png" /> 
         
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
</section>

<!-- Example 2 --->

<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-xs-center text-lg-center">
          
             <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv1QA.png" />  
           </div>
          </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `<img class="img-responsive" src="some_image.jpg">` use it

Comment: i tried but it still doesn't work.. when i change screen size the character/mascot is going down from header like this: https://i.imgur.com/pFmpy8K.png

Comment: @NurçinÖzer Can You update Your Question With Full Code